# IFNULL around a complicated Case Function select column

Tags: sql, case, sql-null, ifnull

How do I fix my IFNULL so that it doesn't break the below? If I remove the IFNULL than it works fine, but I need to calculate data off that column and need to get rid of the null values and replace with a 0.

```
 IFNULL(CASE 
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Transportation & Warehousing' THEN 26
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Construction' THEN 19
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Field Services' THEN 26
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Wholesale Trade' THEN 26
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Manufacturing' THEN 30
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Consumer Products' THEN 26
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Retail Trade' THEN 26
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Passenger Transit' THEN 25
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Mining, Quarrying, Oil & Gas' THEN 25
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Food & Beverage' THEN 26
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Utilities' THEN 26
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Health Care & Social Assistance' THEN 25
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Government' THEN 26
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Educational Services' THEN 25
    ELSE 254
    END * Number_Of_Vehicles *0.99) + 
(CASE 
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Transportation & Warehousing' THEN 34
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Construction' THEN 32
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Field Services' THEN 33
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Wholesale Trade' THEN 36
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Manufacturing' THEN 39
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Consumer Products' THEN 42
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Retail Trade' THEN 31
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Passenger Transit' THEN 32
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Mining, Quarrying, Oil & Gas' THEN 32
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Food & Beverage' THEN 23
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Utilities' THEN 32
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Health Care & Social Assistance' THEN 32
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Government' THEN 42
    WHEN A.Industry = 'Educational Services' THEN 39
    ELSE 32
    END * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.49),0)
```

Tried to add an ifnull, but unsure how to do that in this case with the correct format.

Comment: `mysql` <> `google-bigquery`. I removed the conflicting tags, plus tag only one database.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate issue is with parentheses, that are not well balanced. You don't need parentheses around the `CASE`s, only one pair is needed, for the `IFNULL()` function.

Also, you could simplify the `CASE` expressions so that the checked column is not repeated again and again. I also find that it would be easier to follow if there was a single `CASE` expressions with `WHEN` branches managing the whole arithmetic, rather than two distinct expressions with similar branches.

We could phrase this as:

```
IFNULL(
    CASE A.Industry 
        WHEN 'Transportation & Warehousing'     THEN 26 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.99 + 34 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.49
        WHEN 'Construction'                     THEN 19 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.99 + 32 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.49
        WHEN 'Field Services'                   THEN 26 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.99 + 33 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.49
        WHEN 'Wholesale Trade'                  THEN 26 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.99 + 36 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.49
        WHEN 'Manufacturing'                    THEN 30 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.99 + 39 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.49
        WHEN 'Consumer Products'                THEN 26 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.99 + 42 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.49
        WHEN 'Retail Trade'                     THEN 26 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.99 + 31 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.49
        WHEN 'Passenger Transit'                THEN 25 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.99 + 32 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.49
        WHEN 'Mining, Quarrying, Oil & Gas'     THEN 25 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.99 + 32 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.49
        WHEN 'Food & Beverage'                  THEN 26 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.99 + 23 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.49
        WHEN 'Utilities'                        THEN 26 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.99 + 32 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.49
        WHEN 'Health Care & Social Assistance'  THEN 25 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.99 + 32 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.49
        WHEN 'Government'                       THEN 26 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.99 + 42 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.49
        WHEN 'Educational Services'             THEN 25 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.99 + 39 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.49
        ELSE                                        254 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.99 + 32 * Number_Of_Vehicles * 0.49
    END,
    0
)
```